# Where can I find a suitable online dictionary?

Tags: discussion

I tried http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/ and it is not that useful.

I want a good online dictionary which can help me study Japanese.

It would be helpful if it can translate whole line, for example, in this line "泣き出した　暗い空と" from a Japanese song, there are obviously 2 sentences or 2 phrases. If one doesn't know the composition of the sentence, it would be better to translate the whole line first.

I am sure this would be closed. So please make this a community wiki.

I've noticed the thread [I am looking for an online Japanese dictionary with audio pronunciations](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/i-am-looking-for-an-online-japanese-dictionary-with-audio-pronunciations) and I think my question is more general than that because I don't require pronunciation.

Comment: I think that you are looking for a translation service instead of a dictionary.

Comment: This question is both off-topic (and probably answered many times over, here or in Meta... but I don't have time to go digging now). Unless anybody has a good argument for keeping it here, I am closing and migrating it...

Answer (score 10):

Dictionaries don't work like that. Babel Fish, Google Translate, et alia can give you machine translations, but they're not that accurate. If you really want to study Japanese, you have to learn the grammar.

> If one don't know the composition of the sentence, it would be better
>   to translate the whole line first.

This is inaccurate. It should be:

> If one don't know the composition of the sentence, one can't translate the whole line.

Comment: To add onto that, trying to translate a full line with a machine translation service usually doesn't end well.  But if you break that line into chunks (based on major particle boundaries), most of the time you can get a fairly close translation.  So knowing the composition _really_ is invaluable.

Answer (score 2):

Its translation of  google bot. You can invite them from  your mail.

en2ja@bot.talk.google.com (translate English to japanese)

ja2en@bot.talk.google.com (translate japanese to English)

Its online japanese Dictionary.
http://www.jisho.org/